# Python - Best way to replace an element in a list with a key value from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

As the title says.
What's the best way to replace an element in a list, with a key value from a dictionary?

I have the following list: `['X', 'R', 'Y', 'F']` and the dictionary: `('X': ['X', 'R', 'Y', 'F'])` I'd like to look through the list and replace each element which is equals to the key in the dictionary with the value in the dictionary.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of what you want your input and result to look like?

Comment: Edit your question and put that information in your question since it is important to the question rather than putting it in a comment.

Comment: So your output list would look like `[['X', 'R', 'Y', 'F'], 'R', 'Y', 'F']`?

Comment: Yes, and I just updated the description of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lst = ['X', 'R', 'Y', 'F'] 
replacements = {'X': ['X', 'R', 'Y', 'F']}
new_lst = [replacements.get(i, i) for i in lst]
print new_lst     # [['X', 'R', 'Y', 'F'], 'R', 'Y', 'F']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# The input list
myList = ['X', 'R', 'Y', 'F']

# The input dictionary
myDict = {'X': ['X', 'R', 'Y', 'F']}

# Iterate through every element in the list
for iterator, element in enumerate(myList):
    # If the current element is present in the input dictionary
    if element in myDict.keys():
        # Replace the element
        myList[iterator] = myDict[element]

# Print the transformed list
print myList
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to your answer? Code-only answers are frowned upon on SO.

Comment: @honk Is it not simple enough to understand without any explanation? I believe anyone who knows Python will be able to understand it without any problem. Also, the other answer also lacks any explanation; would you care to inform him about it too?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I commented on your answer because it showed up in the low-quality queue. I just wanted to motivate you, to improve your answer. Of course there are other answers which should be improved. But this should not be the reason to ignore quality at all. There are many Q&As on this topic on meta, e.g., [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260411/2675154). Maybe just one sentence of introduction on your key idea would already do the trick.

Comment: I think so :) Thank you for your effort!